# How to make a multiple line chart with series color determined by another property

Tags: angular, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm currently building a angular project where i need to draw a line chart with multiple datasets.

- Angular 14
- dc.js 4.2.7

Each line should represent a mac address and the line color should be defined by each dataset property.
So basically groupped by 2 diferent properties.
The object to map  datasets comes in this format :

```
{
  id: "string",
  datasets: [
    id: "string",
    data: [];
    color: "string";
  ]
}
```

Before i had to put the colors i followed some examples, joinned all data from datasets and made a series chart for the mac addresses

```
// generate charts
var chart_width = null,
  chart_height = null;
var chartObjet = dc.seriesChart("#chart");

    chartObjet.height(chart_height).width(chart_width)
  .margins({ top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40 })
  .chart(function(c) {
    return dc.lineChart(c)
            .renderDataPoints({ radius: 2, fillOpacity: 0.8, strokeOpacity: 0.1 });
  })
  .clipPadding(10)
  
  .dimension(chartDimension)
  .group(chartDimension.group())
  .seriesAccessor(function(d) {
    return d.key[1];
  })
  .keyAccessor(function(d) {
    return d.key[0];
  })
  .valueAccessor(function(d) {
    return +d.value;
  })
  .x(xScale)
  .xUnits(xUnits);
chartObjet.render();
```

But i could not find any example to also group it by color and after experimenting a bit with dc colors, i could never managed to make it work. Is this possible ?

Heres a fiddle with my currently chart:
https://jsfiddle.net/TheAndre98/zexncpd5/41/

Comment: By "group by color", I guess you mean that you want a line per mac address, but color the lines based on some other property? Indeed, there isn't any way to "group" the lines, but you should be able to assign colors to lines based on a property that is not the series. Have you looked at `.colorAccessor()`?

Comment: Yes, i've updated my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/TheAndre98/zexncpd5/62/
It changes colors but it should be 3 Lines there since there is datasets with 3 colors.